# update last record of each cluster

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and I already create the lead values for the next date in each product cluster. In addition to that I created a delta value which displays the difference between date and lead_date.

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| Product |    Date    |  LeadDate  | delta_days |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| A       | 2018-01-15 | 2018-01-23 | 8          |
| A       | 2018-01-23 | 2018-02-19 | 27         |
| A       | 2018-02-19 | 2017-05-25 | -270       |
| B       | 2017-05-25 | 2017-05-30 | 5          |
| B       | 2017-05-30 | 2016-01-01 | -515       |
| C       | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-02 | 1          |
| C       | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-03 | 1          |
| C       | 2016-01-03 | NULL       | NULL       |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
```

What I want to do is that I need to update the last record of each product cluster and set Lead_date and delta_days to null. How should I do this?

This is my goal:

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| Product |    Date    |  LeadDate  | delta_days |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| A       | 2018-01-15 | 2018-01-23 | 8          |
| A       | 2018-01-23 | 2018-02-19 | 27         |
| A       | 2018-02-19 | NULL       | NULL       |
| B       | 2017-05-25 | 2017-05-30 | 5          |
| B       | 2017-05-30 | NULL       | NULL       |
| C       | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-02 | 1          |
| C       | 2016-01-02 | 2016-01-03 | 1          |
| C       | 2016-01-03 | NULL       | NULL       |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Do a Select statement to return the last record of each cluster, then do an update joining on Date and product of your result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lag/Lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) have a default value if it can't find the next/previous value:

```
LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])  
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

Just specify that you want the `[default]` to be NULL in your code to produce your lead column

In your code (guess since we don't have it):

```
SELECT date, 
LEAD([date], 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY [date]) as your_new_col
```

IMO, this is better than running an actual update since this will be dynamic in case you insert a new record that will change the existing order of your records.

Comment: @not_ur_avg_cookie Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use updatable `cte` with [`last_value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function :

```
with updatable as (
        select *, last_value(date) over (partition by product order by date) as last_val
        from table 
)

update updatable 
set LeadDate = null, delta_days = null
where Date = last_val;
```